# Convert the data type of the value of the dictionary from float to percentage with two decimals, remove some punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary `d`, the data type of the value is `float`, since this value is ***the accuracy rate***. So I want to convert it to a `percentage`:

```
d = {'import': 0.5833333333333334, 'export': 0.4166666666666667}
d.values()
d.items()
for k, v in d.items():
     d[v] = d[format(v,'.2%')]
```

The ultimate goal is to remove the quotation marks and curly braces on the key, and convert it into a string to pass in the title of a matplotlib plot:

```
plt.title(f"Models accuracy is :\n{str(d)}")
```

The title of the figure will become like this:

```
Models accuracy is ：
import: 58.33%, export: 41.67%
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
# format each metric
# this will give you 2 decimal places
results = [f"{key}:{100*d[key]:.2f}%" for key in d]

# combine into a single string
results_combined = ", ".join(results)

# set as title
title = f"Models accuracy is :\n{results_combined}"
```